# Basic constructions for graded algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

I'm reading about the Weil algebra of a Lie group and it involves some constructions I'm not very familiar with, for instance the "free graded-commutative graded algebra on $a_1...a_n$ with degrees $deg(a_i)$." Does anyone know a good source for *basic* graded-algebra constructions like this?  Anything i find is either too basic or too advanced to do these constructions in detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by reading the first part of Kassel's [Quantum Groups](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Quantum_Groups.html?id=S1KE_pToY98C&redir_esc=y).

Let us give some examples involving graded constructions.
We focus on graded vector spaces over a field; the module theory is similar.
It seems you are interested in the graded symmetric algebra over a graded vector space.

In general, let $V:=\{V_i\}_{i\in\mathbb Z}$ be a $\mathbb Z$-graded vector field over $\mathbb R$: every homogeneous component $V_i$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$.
Elements $a_i\in V_i$ are said of being homogeneous of degree $|a_i|:=i$. The free graded algebra over $V$ is the tensor algebra $T(V)$, which, as a set, is given by
$$T(V)=\mathbb R\oplus V\oplus V^{\otimes 2}\oplus V^{\otimes 3}\oplus\dots $$

Its homogeneous component $T^i:= T(V)^i$ of degree $i$ is then

$$T^i:=\bigoplus_{j\geq 0}(V^{\otimes j})^i, $$

and $(V^{\otimes j})^i:=\oplus_{i_1+...+i_j=i} V^{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes V^{i_j}.$
 Note that the index $j$ is not a grading: it is called the "weight". The associative product is given by concatenation of tensors and the unit is the multiplicative unit $1\in \mathbb R$.

Let $(R)$ be the two sided graded ideal in $T(V)$ generated by all the expressions of the form

$$v\otimes w -(-1)^{|v_i||w_j|}w\otimes v, $$

for all $v$ and $w$ in $V$ homogeneous of degrees $|i|$ and $|j|$. In other words,

$$(R)=T(V)\otimes R\otimes T(V) $$

with $R:=\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb R}(v\otimes w -(-1)^{|v_i||w_j|}w\otimes v)$.
Note that $R\subset V^{\otimes 2}$. We denote by $(R)_j$, $j\geq 2$ the component(s) of the ideal $(R)$ in $V^{\otimes j}$, i.e.

$$(R)_2=R, $$
$$(R)_3=V\otimes R\oplus R\otimes V, $$

and so on. Once again, the index $j$ denotes the "weight", and not the grading.

We are done: the quotient 
$$S(V):=T(V)/ (R)=\mathbb R\oplus V\oplus V^{\otimes 2}/R\oplus V^{\otimes 3}/(R)_3 \oplus\dots  $$

is the graded symmetric algebra over $V$.

The case with a finite number of letters $a_1,...a_n$ in the OP can be reduced to the case of a finite dimensional graded vector space $V$ (with all homogeneous components $V_i$ finite dimensional, and in finite number different from $\{0\}$).

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: you are welcome!